# How to make JWT token authorization optional in controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I use JWT tokens in my ASP.NET Core 2 web application

If the JWT token fails I still want the controller method to be hit but the ASP.NET Identity `User` object will just be null. Currently the controller method won't get entered if authentication fails so I can't apply logic inside the method to deal with non authenticated users which I want to deal with as guests instead of blocking them.

My code:

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidIssuer = _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = _config["Tokens:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]))
                };

            });
```

When a user logs in

```
   private IActionResult CreateToken(ApplicationUser user, IList<string> roles)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
          new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Id.ToString()),
          new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
          new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName)
        };



        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Tokens:Key"]));

        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
          _config["Tokens:Issuer"],
          _config["Tokens:Audience"],
          claims.ToArray(),
         expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
          signingCredentials: creds);

        var results = new
        {
            token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
            expiration = token.ValidTo,
        };

        return Created("", results);
```

I make sure after authenticated the various API calls pass the JWT token.

In my Controller I make use of an Authorize attribute

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
 public class MyController : Controller
{
```

This allows me to capture the logged in user with the following code for the various API calls

```
 var loggedInUser = User.Identity.Name;
```

If I remove the authorize attribute then `User.Identity.Name` will always be null even if the user is authenticated.

How do I use the authorize attribute but still allow the controller method to be entered if the token is not valid? I want to use the same method for both Authorized and non Authorized users to be entered. I will then use the `User.Identity.Name` to determine if they are not authenticated and have guest user logic inside the method for them.

Comment: I think you can write your own **Authorize** attribute e.g. `AuthorizeWithGuests` and put the logic inside of that attribute where you will do your checks and see if the user is not authenticated than treat that users as a guest.

Comment: I don't know the internals of the current Authorize attribute and I assume I have to rewrite it since I can't inherit from it since it blocks access

Comment: Yep exactly you have to write your own code there and just use it like this 
`[AuthorizeWithGuests]`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's actually easier than you might expect. You can just use *both* `Authorize` and `AllowAnonymous`, like so:

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class MyController : Controller
```

If authorization was successful, you'll have an authenticated `User` (`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true`), otherwise, you will have an anonymous `User`.

Comment: This will also bypass any security you thought you had in place on the controller.

Comment: @Brad I wanted to handle the security inside the controller but still have the User.Identity populated which the Authorize attribute does. Kirk's solution solves this for me

Comment: Is it possible inside such a  method to determine if a valid, but expired token was provided? Would I have to poke around in some Http Headers to extract the token and validate it myself?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Yeah, I think you'd have to pull out the header yourself and manage it that way. Depending on what you're looking to do, you might want to consider using the [`JwtBearerEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents?view=aspnetcore-2.2) hook which works at a more cross-cutting level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when this changed but my application is on ASP.NET Core 3.1 and without my actions/endpoints specifying that I require authorization, the authentication middleware still provides the information I require inside my ClaimsPrincipal when a valid token is provided and a blank principal when no token is specified.

Comment: This behaviour continues in .NET 5. If you add Authentication middleware in Startup, the User.Identity object in HttpContext is filled in case of a valid token even if you do not decorate your class or method with Authorize attribute.

Comment: it throws an error if token is invalid. @MÇT

Answer (score 0):

By updating the ASP.NET Core a little bit, besides configuring your token guidelines, you can enable your controllers to require Bearer Token authentication by adding:

**Startup.cs**

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddJwtSecurity(
                signingConfigurations, tokenConfigurations);
  }
```

Remembering that if you want to block the entire controller at once, just add it at the top of the Authorize class.

```
namespace <name_controller>
{    
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [RequireHttps]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class clientesController : Controller
    {
    }
}
```