# ASP.NET Core optional JWT Bearer Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

does ASP.NET Core (WebAPI) provide a way to use optional JWT Bearer tokens? I want to make an action accessible with and without a token and decide which informations to return (also based on the claims inside the token).

I tried it this way:

```
var bearer = Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");

var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler(); //replace with the actual Handler set up in services
var decodedValue = handler.ReadJwtToken(bearer);
```

I could build upon this, but maybe ASP.NET Core already provides a more elegant solution?

Comment: can't you split the use case to have a separate action? otherwise the proposed option is a way to go. but with few null checks.

Comment: Yeah would be a possibility, but then I have to duplicate all paths, I I will have round about 10-15 Paths I think ... :/ Or maybe I have to enforce a token to use my API (Kind of an access token with or without special claims)

Comment: How about not guarding your endpoint anymore, then with anonymous request, `HttpContext.User` should be null and vice versa. One if statement per endpoint ? Cause `Authentication` process was optional since the beginning, any request that can be process downstream.

Comment: Going full anonymous would be a way, but then I have to check for a token manually like I stated in my question and read all the claims myself. :/

Comment: Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686237/how-to-make-jwt-token-authorization-optional-in-controller-methods?rq=1